# why allocating char on the free store giving wrong value?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17

I'm allocating memory on the free store and putting the char on that storage,  but it giving some unexpected output in long input of char, and on my pc it giving me unexpected result for more than even 1 char of input, but if i comment out `delete [] p;` in `add_char()`, it give expected result.

[image: that's what im getting on my pc][see demo on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rzbzcsrTj)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>


char* add_char(char* p, char ch) 
{
    char* pc = new char[strlen(p) + 1];

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= strlen(p); ++i) {
        if (i == strlen(p))
            pc[i] = ch;

        else
            pc[i] = p[i];
    }

    delete[] p;
    return pc;
}
int main()
{
    char ch = 0; 
    char* pc = new char[1]{'a'};

    while (std::cin >> ch && ch != '!') {
        pc = add_char(pc, ch);

    }
    std::cout << "pc : " << pc << "\n";
    std::cout << strlen(pc) << "\n";;
}
```

Comment: strlen() is looking for zero. You have allocated single char, where is termination?

Comment: C-style strings are really called ***null-terminated** strings*. A string of one character needs space for *two*, to also fit the null-terminator character `'\0'`. Use `std::string` for all your string needs in C++, and consider C-style strings as an intermediate topic that shouldn't be needed by beginners.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i can't use std::string, it asked me to use c-style string, how i can make it correct  ?

Comment: Begin with "a string of one character needs space for two, to also fit the null-terminator character '\0'" (from my previous comment). Then think about that null-terminator character, because it's not added automatically to strings you create dynamically.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , now its working [link](https://godbolt.org/z/Yb1qca7d9), can you check , is there any other efficient method or any UB. that would me much helpful.

Comment: The code in the link has a `new[]` but no matching `delete[]`, so is leaking the final `pc`.  When you say "**it** asked me to use c-style string", what is **it** that is asking you?

Comment: @Eljay it's a question from a book called PPP (bjarne's book)

Comment: I've got that book.  What is the question from the book?

Comment: @Eljay it's "write a program that reads characters from ```cin``` into an array that you have allocate on the free store. Read individual characters until an exclamation mark (!) is entered. Do not use a std::string. Do not worry about memory exhaustion. **page no. 624**

Comment: Thank you.  No where in the exercise description does it say you should make a C-style string.  It says to make an array.  A non-C-style string array cannot use `strlen`.  Keep track of the length in another variable.

Comment: @Eljay yes, but in c++ we can only have an array of fixed size, so that limit us to use an array of predetermined size, now in this example i can have an array of char as long as i want, also you can't determine the size of an array allocated on free store, so we need a terminated zero that allow us to find the end of an array allocated on the free store.

Comment: @Eljay and keeping track of length  in a variable make the function look so verbose and ugly because we also need to that variable to return to main() function then we reach to the point where either we return a struct or pass that variable as reference argument.

Comment: You can make a dynamic array, `char* p = new char[size];`  It does not need to be a fixed-sized array.

Comment: @Eljay yes, but if we want to print that returned pointer to free store allocated array in main() function then either we need terminated zero in that array or we need that variable.

Comment: You can print the characters out one-by-one, or you can print them out `cout << string(p, p+size) << "\n";` in one shot.  (That does not violate the constraints of the question.)  Alternatively, you could use a `string_view` and print that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strlen` relies on null character `\0` to calculate the length of the given string, so you have to provide it for both initial value:

```cpp
char* pc = new char[]{'a', '\0'};
```

..and keep it while appending the inserted characters one by one:

```cpp
const std::size_t newLength = strlen(p) + 2; // +1 for null terminator (strlen ignores) and +1 for new character
char* pc = new char[newLength];


for (size_t i = 0; i < newLength; ++i) {
    if (i == newLength - 1)
        pc[i] = '\0';
    else if (i == newLength - 2)
        pc[i] = ch;
    else
        pc[i] = p[i];
}
```

**P.S.** alternatively you can drop use of `strlen` and keep the array length elsewhere

Comment: Your loop is more complicated than it needs to be. Invoking the `if` checks on every iteration is unnecessary. Appending `ch` and `'\0'` shouldn't even be inside the loop at all. Moving them out of the loop will greatly simplify the loop.

Comment: I agree, but i tend to keep the answers as close as possible to the original code snippet, in order to focus on the issues the question asks about. (so other changes don't get OP confused about what the root cause of the problem is)

Answer (score 1):

C-style strings are **null-terminated**, meaning they end with a `'\0'` character. But you are not terminating any of your `char[]` strings with `'\0'` at all.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

char* add_char(char* p, char ch) 
{
    size_t len = std::strlen(p);
    char* pc = new char[len + 2]; // +1 for ch, +1 for terminator

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        pc[i] = p[i];
    }
    // alternatively:
    // std::strcpy(pc, p);

    pc[len+0] = ch;
    pc[len+1] = '\0';

    delete[] p;
    return pc;
}

int main()
{
    char* pc = new char[2]{'a', '\0'};

    char ch;
    while (std::cin >> ch && ch != '!') {
        pc = add_char(pc, ch);
    }

    std::cout << "pc : " << pc << '\n';
    std::cout << std::strlen(pc) << '\n';

    delete[] pc;
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/mLPDOf)